# "Never saw" versus "didn't ever see"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, differences, negation, negative-polarity-items

Do these sentences have different meanings?

> 1. I *never saw* such a thing.
>
>    I *didn't ever see* such a thing.
> 2. I *never saw* him dancing.
>
>    I *didn't ever see* him dancing.

My questions:

- Are both usages correct?
- Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: Not sure, but "didn't ever [verb]" just sounds awkward--probably because it can be replaced with the simpler "never".

Comment: @Luke Was this possibly "such thing" before yasar fixed it? If so, it probably meant 'such-and-such' or simply 'X' - "I never saw such a thing" suggests shock, distress or outrage!

Comment: Yes, it was (take a look at the edits). *Such a thing* can also suggest surprise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, ***Negative Polarity*** again.

(BTW, I am informed that there is now an NPI tag, which anyone is allowed to use to mark questions with. Feel free.)

Whenever you see a negative (like *never*) in a sentence, you know you've got trouble. **Especially** if you see more than one, or if there's a modal in the sentence as well. Luckily, that's not the case here.

First, NPIs. The word *ever* means *at any time*, i.e, **anywhen*. But people don't say **anywhen* (the asterisk means it's ungrammatical); they say *ever* instead, the same way they don't say **all two*,
but rather  say *both* instead.

The interesting thing about the word *ever* is that it's a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) (NPI), like *any*; indeed, it's just a variant of *any*. NPIs can't occur outside a negative context, which is why it sounds so awful to say

- **I have ever been there.*

That's why there's a *not* in

- *I have not ever been there.*

*Never* is just a contraction of *not ever*, the same way *none* is a contraction for *not one*.

- *I have never been there.*

Both of those are fine, because they're negative. One is a contraction of the other, so there's no meaning difference.

As for *such a thing*, it's an idiom, in this case a pretty frozen one, which indicates surprise at the extreme nature of whatever the "thing" is sposta be. So you get to express surprised indignation at the same time you deny experience of extremes. Pretty useful phrase.

Comment: Good answer (I guess), but I didn't understand the conclusion. Do you mean both usages are same and valid?

Comment: Yes. Just like _He has done it_ and _He's done it_ are same and valid. Contractions don't change meaning.

Comment: I say 'anywhen', and so did Thomas Carlyle. ‘Ever’ outside a negative context hasn’t always been ungrammatical, and I’m not sure it is now. We still say, if a little self-consciously, ‘It was ever thus’.

Comment: Fixed phrases are exceptions to any rule. They preserve archaic structures, like fossils in the landscape; in the UK, where Englishes have been spoken the longest, they often preserve archaic local structures. However, they **are** fossils, and they're not really productive in Modern English.

Answer (score 2):

Both usages are correct.

They mean the same thing.

However, the scope of the first is more comprehensive.  "I never" implies "in my whole life."  "I didn't ever" implies "while I was there at that event we're discussing."

Both are mere implications; unless stated, either scope can be understood.

Comment: Both usaages are correct, and the meanings are identical.  I don't agree with your third paragraph though; you may find that in some regions, one is more common than the other, but I would be very surprised if you find any region at all where the meaning differs.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a subtle difference in meaning, at least in my dialect:  "I didn't ever..." often has more force/emphasis than "I never.."  One may say, "I never saw him do that".  The emphasis is on "saw" and the implication could be that *he may have done it for all I know, but I didn't **see** it.*  But if I say, "I didn't ever see him do that", then the emphasis is on "ever", which gives an implication is more along the lines of *I don't think it **ever** happened*.
As I said, it's not 100% consistent, but there often is that distinction.  You have to rely on context for full clarity.

Answer (score 1):

In everyday speech, most people use "I didn't..." and "I never..." interchangeably. However, there is a subtle difference. The use of "never" can be used to imply that something is no longer possible, or is very unlikely to happen. For example:

- "I didn't see that Broadway musical." - this simply means you did not see the show, and does not imply anything about the future.
- "I never saw that Broadway musical." - this could be used to refer to a show that is no longer playing, so it would no longer be possible to see it.